# What are the differences between MLP and DNN?

Tags: mlp, deep-learning

So I have been reading about the topic for a while, but i did not find a clear answer why MLP and DNN are being used interchangeably even though there are some differences between them.

So far I have filtered some informations:

"The field of artificial neural networks is often just called neural networks or multi-layer perceptrons after perhaps the most useful type of neural network.
A perceptron is a single neuron(input, output, weights, activation) model that was a precursor to larger neural networks.

MLP is a subset of DNN.
While DNN can have loops and MLP are always feed-forward(a type of Neural Network architecture where the connections are "fed forward", do not form cycles (like in recurrent nets).
Multilayer Perceptron is a finite acyclic graph, not like RNN and it's subsets which are cyclic in nature.
MLP uses back propagation for training the network."

So what makes MLP different from DNN ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You explained it already quite well. An MLP is a type of neural network, the same way CNNs, RNNs, and other types exist. DNN is an umbrella term for all types of neural networks.

The reason some literature may be using these terms interchangeably is likely due to the fact that MLPs are some of the oldest forms of neural networks and therefore, at the time the literature was written, MLPs and DNNs were ubiquitous.

Comment: I have read that this confusion is linked to old literature, but some people argue that the reason might the number of layers, or if they're fully connected or not, and the complexity of the models. Moreover on Kaggle people are having the liberty to use them interchangeably in different contexts.

Comment: Another thing is, on SKLEARN, you can call and use MLP as simple as using a logistic regression, and it's called MLP indeed but you cannot create a DNN from it, but with other frameworks like Tensorflow and Pytorch you have the liberty to create a DNN from MLP's (one hidden layer). So i wanted to get to the bottom of this controversy.

Comment: There is a good answer from 2017 on cross-validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/315402/multi-layer-perceptron-vs-deep-neural-network

Comment: what do they mean by "DNN can have loops" ??

Comment: Can you maybe share what literature you are referring to? Besides that, loops like refer to recurrent networks

Comment: It's from the accepted answer of the link you have shared. If loop refers to RNN, why not call it by its explicit name, instead, they have said "DNN". I get, the confusion is because of the literature, but the advancement that has taken place made these terms technically different, yet in the AI community they use these terms interchangeably, and that's what concerns me. Moreover, the answers are contradictory, but the best I think is the second one, in the link that you have shared, which I have already consulted yesterday.

Comment: Deep learning is a fast moving field and there isn't an incredible will to be as semantically rigid as other fields (statistics come to mind). But I can assure you that I have never seen people use DNN is any technical paper. Papers refer to the specific type of networks, and to be honest, I never ran into a situation where I didn't know what the author was referring to